# Simplify $B(ix,2+iy,0)$ whre $B$ is the incomplete Beta function

Tags: special-functions, beta-function

Is there any way to re-write or simplify this function for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, in the limit $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$? Or any laws regarding symmetry with respect to $x\rightarrow -x$ or $y\rightarrow -y$?

The reason for asking this question is that I have a lengthy term that contains a sum of all kinds of combinations like $B(ix,2\pm iy,0)\pm B(\pm ix,2\pm iy,0)$. All relations that I found for the incomplete Beta function are invalid for the last argument being zero.

My hypothesis is that

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{-B(-ix,2+iy,0)}{e^{\pi y}B(ix,2+iy,0))}=1$

but I'm struggling with the proof.

Comment: Is $B(a, b, c)$ $\int_0^a t^{b-1}(1-t)^{c-1} dt$ as usual? That doesn't seem to make very much sense here.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition I'm working with.